# Covid Vaccine Documentation to enter Spain

Tags: covid-19, spain

I know things are changing rapidly, but:

Does anyone know what is an acceptable proof of vaccination from the U.S. when travelling to Spain?

Is the CDC Card good enough?  A doctor's letter?  Do I need the physical document, or is an image acceptable?

Comment: This might shed some light https://es.usembassy.gov/message-to-u-s-citizens-requirements-for-vaccinated-u-s-citizens-and-their-minor-children-to-enter-spain-effective-june-7-2021/

Answer (score 1):

From the U.S. Embassy in Spain (June 8, 2021):

> At this time, we do not have additional details about which specific
> vaccine certificates, such as those provided by the CDC, will be
> accepted to allow entry for U.S. citizens into Spain.  Please refer to
> the Spain Travel Health portal (FAQs), and we will update our website
> with this information as soon as it is available.